# Which index to create in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, query-performance

I have a table:

```
row_id          attr_id    attr_val
180000001       100        test1
180000001       101        test2
180000001       102        test3
180000001       103        test4
180000001       104        test5
180000002       100        test6
180000002       101        test7
180000002       102        test8
180000002       103        test9
180000002       104        test10
```

It has over 5 billion rows and the table size is around 1.4 TB. I generally run the following query:

```
select * from table1 where rec_id = 180000002;
```

and

```
select * from table1 where rec_id = 180000002 and va_id = 100;
```

What type of index should I be applying in Postgres to be most efficient given the space and my use case?

Comment: `rec_id` or `row_id`? `va_id` or `attr_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these queries, you want the following index: `(rec_id, va_id)`.

Do you *really* mean `select *`? If you are able to reduce the number of columns in the `select` clause to just a few columns, then you might want to add them to the index as well.

As an example, a query like:

```
select col1, col2 from table1 where rec_id = 180000002 and va_id = 100;
```

Would benefit index `(rec_id, va_id, col1, col2)`: this makes the index *covering*, it the database might be able to execute it entirely by looking at the index only.

Comment: Should I use Btree or Brin? If I use Btree, the index creation takes a lot of time and is very big.

Comment: @dang: you might want and try both. BRIN is less expensive but might be less efficient too.